# How to handle with answer ratio in our main site?

Tags: discussion, answers

In [area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism), it is showing that answer ratio is 1.6. It means there is 1.6 answer to every question on average.

Almost all questions asked in main site are answerable from scriptures only and are fact based. So a single answer contains enough details and another answer to the same question will be redundant in most of the cases.

Keep the questions with zero answers aside and consider the questions having a proper single answer.

Then what can one do to increase the answer ratio?

Comment: [Queries on “Answer Ratio” towards the site graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300667/357396) which was originally asked on our site and migrated to Meta Stack Exchange. Look at that answer.

Comment: May I know the reason you ask/care about answer ratio? If it's about site graduation, then the answer ratio is not the most important stats (see also [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614), though currently, no new sites are graduating [since October 2017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290363) even if they have spectacular stats).

Comment: @Andrew T. Yeah, graduation is a reason. Another is that for many questions more than a single answer will be redundant( new answers contain the same information as an existing one). May I know the reason for not graduating a site with enough stats?

Comment: @hanugm we don't really know either. It's something that confused some of us and made many discussions related to site graduation on Meta SE, with the latest: [Writing.SE clamours for graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322781).